# Function that take 2 data types parameters, prints one and iterates for the next one

Tags: haskell, algebraic-data-types

I am designing an interpreter from my AST and I am stuck on one part of this where I have to evaluate and print one datatype and iterate on the list of the other.

Here are the datatypes based on the AST.

```
data Match = Matching Patt Expr deriving (Eq,Show,Read)

data Rules = Ruling Match [Rules] deriving (Eq,Show,Read)
```

The rules function is supposed to evaluate Match and iterate over the rules to print them too. Here is the function and what I have tried with no luck

```
evalMatch::Match -> String
evalMatch (Matching patt expr) = evalPatt patt ++ evalExpr expr

evalRules::Rules -> Match -> [Rules] -> String
evalRules (Ruling match [rules]) = do evalMatch match 
                                  listRules [rules]
evalRules::Rules -> Match -> [Rules] -> String
evalRules (Ruling match [rules]) = do evalMatch match 
                                   listRules [rules]
                                   --also tried = evalMatch match ++ listRules [rules]

listRules::[Rules] -> String
listRules [] = []
listRules (x:xs) = show x ++ listRules xs
```

I am new to Haskell to any help greatly appreciated.

The compiler error I am getting is

> - Couldn't match expected type `Match -> [Rules] -> String'
>                   with actual type`[Char]'
>
>   - In a stmt of a 'do' block: evalMatch match
>       In the expression:
>       do evalMatch match
>          listRules [rules]
>       In an equation for `evalRules':
>         evalRules (Ruling match [rules])
>           = do evalMatch match
>                listRules [rules]

Comment: Please include a self-contained example that others can run, as well as the error you're getting and what you don't understand about the error message. It looks like you have a syntax error (read about layout of `do` blocks; each line should have the same indentation), as well as a lot of misunderstandings (e.g. `[rules]` on the lefthand-side of `=` matches _a list with a single element_ and binds it to `rules`)

Comment: The following things are missing from your problem statement: `Patt`, `Expr`, `evalMatch`, and the exact error or behavior that you are currently stuck in debugging.

Comment: The datatypes that are missing are irrelevant for the error I am stuck, otherwise, I would have to provide the entire tree. @jberryman I will edit with the error message

Answer (score 0):

The error you're getting says:

> ```
> Couldn't match expected type `Match -> [Rules] -> String' with actual type `[Char]'
> ```

This tells you what's wrong: The expected type of `evalRules` is `Rules -> Match -> [Rules] -> String` (this is according to the type signature you wrote), but the actual type of the function as implemented is `Rules -> [Char]` (or equivalently, `Rules -> String`). In other words, your type signature states that the function should take three arguments, but your implementation only takes one:

```
evalRules :: Rules -> Match -> [Rules] -> String -- three arguments
evalRules (Ruling match [rules]) = ...           -- (Ruling match [rules]) is one argument of type `Rules`
```

You'll need to either add the other two arguments to your implementation, or remove them from your type signature. From what I can tell, you probably want the latter.

---

There are a number of other problems with this code as well:

#### Do notation

When using `do` notation, actions must be indented properly so that they line up:

```
-- incorrect
evalRules (Ruling match [rules]) = do evalMatch match
                                   listRules [rules]
-- correct
evalRules (Ruling match [rules]) = do evalMatch match
                                      listRules [rules]
-- also correct
evalRules (Ruling match [rules]) = do
    evalMatch match
    listRules [rules]
```

As you can see, the calls to `evalMatch` and `listRules` need to start in the same column. Otherwise you'll get parse errors.

#### Monads

You can only use `do` blocks in the context of monads. A monad is any type that implements the `Monad` typeclass, such as `IO` or `Maybe`. Say you're creating an `IO` action: in this case, your function must return an `IO <something>` type, and every action in the `do` block must be of type `IO <something>`. But your `evalRules` returns a type `String` and each action in the `do` block is also type `String`. There's no monadic context here.

(As it turns out, `String` is equivalent to `[Char]`, and `[<something>]` is a monad, so your function as-is will typecheck ... but it probably won't behave the way you expect.)

Right now, the `evalMatch` call in that `do` block doesn't appear to be doing anything (it returns a `String` result which is promptly ignored). If you want to return the `String` result from it alongside the result from `listRules`, you can use the `++` operator to concatenate the strings, instead of using the `do` block. So your comment here is the correct implementation:

```
--also tried = evalMatch match ++ listRules [rules]
```

#### Lists in patterns

You use a pattern `(Ruling match [rules])`, which doesn't do what you probably think it does. When matching a list, you have the following options:

- `(Ruling match [])` matches an empty list on the second argument of `Ruling`.
- `(Ruling match (r:rs))` matches a non-empty list, binding the first element to `r` and the rest of the list to `rs`.
- `(Ruling match [rule1, rule2, rule3])` matches a list with exactly three elements, and binds each element to `rule1`, `rule2`, and `rule3`, respectively.
- `(Ruling match [rule1])` matches a list with **exactly one element**, and binds that element to `rule1`.
- `(Ruling match rules)` matches any list, and binds the list to `rules`. This is probably what you want.

As-is, `evalRules` will only work if the rules list has exactly one element, and will throw an exception otherwise. Removing the brackets will fix this.